# Where are the glyph vendors in secret world?

Tags: the-secret-world

Where are all the glyph vendors in the secret world? Any QL is acceptable, I'm just looking for a comprehensive list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can typically buy a few glyphs from Council of Venice vendors, but there is extremely limited selection here.  I think there's maybe five or so in the whole game, and they sell maybe two glyphs apiece.  **You are much better off crafting your own or buying them off the AH - this is pretty much the only way to get the ones that you'll want.**

This changes a little at the very top end though, since you can get purple QL10 glyphs and upgrade kits from the endgame vendors in your faction base.  (You'll get toolkits drop sometimes from running nightmares anyway, though, so you may well again be better off crafting at least some of these.)

Comment: I crafted all of mine, I didn't even feel I needed to farm anything - just had all the materials by the time I had finished the story line.

Comment: Yeah, you should never really have a shortage of level-appropriate crafting mats.

Comment: Since mayans I've had a huge surplus of mats and QL10 toolkits, and by this point I'm about to start getting purples. Thanks for the info though. =)